# How do different calibers of the same weapon class compare?

Tags: strike-suit-zero

As you progress through the game, you will unlock various weapons, many of which are higher-caliber variants of weapons already in your arsenal: there are 3 plasma guns (CREW 500ep, CREW 1000ep, CREW 1500ep), 2 machine guns (RPE 75mm Pd, RPE 150mm U), 3 guided fighter missiles (S2SFCM Mk I, S2SFCM Mk II and S2SFCM Mk III). They seem to follow a pattern of higher damage, lower fire rate and ammo capacity/energy efficiency, slower projectile speed.

Are higher-caliber versions of these weapons mostly superior to their lesser variants, or is the choice situational/based on preference? Ideally I would like to know their exact stats to make an informed decision.